# geom_bar with multiples variables

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm working in R studio and I'm trying to make a bar chart with 4 different variables on the X axis, and the proportion of each variable observation on the Y axis. My data looks like this:

```
A B C D
1 5 9 0
2 5 9 0
1 5 8 0
1 6 8 0
```

I've tinkered with this code:

```
ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= A), position = "fill")+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= B), position = "fill")+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= C), position = "fill")+
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= D), position = "fill")
```

What I keep ending up with on the X axis is:

1 2 5 6 9 8 0

What I'm trying to put on the X axis is:

A B C D

I appreciate any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

You could reshape your data such using e.g. `tidyr::pivot_longer` such that your variables become categories of one new variable which is named `name` by default, while the values are stored in a new var `value` by default. `value` can then be mapped on `fill`:

```r
data <- read.table(text = "A B C D
1 5 9 0
2 5 9 0
1 5 8 0
1 6 8 0", header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tidyr::pivot_longer(data, everything())
ggplot(data) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x= name, fill = as.factor(value)), position = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks for your help! 

Also, thank you for the help formatting my question!